# Unable to recall jquery function on same class for multiple times

Tags: jquery, html

**My Jquery**

```
$(".edit_inven").click(function(){ 
   $("#edititems").slideDown('slow'); });
```

In below i had created few hyperlinks with same class. when i click on edit hyperlink it should display the content of (edit_inven) div.

If i click again any other edit hyperlink the same effect i should get but its not behaving so plz help me."

**Hyperlinks**

```
<a href='inventory_list.php?pedit_id=$id' class='edit_inven'>Edit</a>
<a href='inventory_list.php?pedit_id=$id' class='edit_inven'>Edit</a>
<a href='inventory_list.php?pedit_id=$id' class='edit_inven'>Edit</a>
<a href='inventory_list.php?pedit_id=$id' class='edit_inven'>Edit</a>



<DIV id='edit_inven' style="display:none">
Blah Blah.....
</DIV>
```

Answer (score 1):

For slideDown to work the element has to be hidden first so try

```
$(".edit_inven").click(function () {
    $("#edititems").hide().slideDown('slow');
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/vJ5xf/), [animated](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/vJ5xf/3/)

Comment: @DhavalMarthak that is why it is working first time... second time on-words it won't work as the element is already displayed... see http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/vJ5xf/2/

Answer (score 0):

You can try this :

If you want that content  should be not slide again on click:

```
$(".edit_inven").click(function (e) {
    $("#edit_inven").slideDown('slow');
    e.preventDefault()
});
```

Happy New Years....:)